# Count how many id share the same identical multiple value

Tags: sql, sql-server

Despite research i maked to find the answer in Stack on advised article i cannot find a way to make this query.

I want to know how many distinct ids share the same group of value (brand, category, start_date and end_date)

**table1:**

| id | brand | category | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Xy-eee2 | mercury | alpha | 05/12/2021 | 16/12/2021 |
| Xd-FF456 | mercury | alpha | 05/12/2021 | 16/12/2021 |
| Xy-234 | mercury | alpha | 05/12/2021 | 16/12/2021 |
| Xd-345 | mercury | alpha | 05/12/2021 | 16/12/2021 |
| Xy-eee2 | mercury | alpha | 05/12/2021 | 16/12/2021 |
| Xd-FFF21 | venus | beta | 20/03/2021 | 25/04/2021 |
| Xy-eee2 | venus | beta | 20/03/2021 | 25/04/2021 |
| Xd-FF23 | venus | beta | 20/03/2021 | 25/04/2021 |
| Xd-FF45 | mars | beta | 01/03/2022 | 06/08/2021 |

Expected result :

| brand | category | start_date | end_date | number_of_distinct_id_matching |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| mercury | alpha | 05/12/2021 | 16/12/2021 | 5 |
| venus | beta | 20/03/2021 | 25/04/2021 | 3 |
| mars | beta | 01/03/2022 | 06/08/2021 | 1 |

Answer (score 0):

Is that what you need?

```
Select brand, category, min(start_date) start_date, max(end_date) end_date, count(1) [Count]
FROM table_name
group by  brand, category
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!
I'm looking for the count of distinct id who match with every duplicate of brand, category, start_date and end_date.

Your query doesn't include the id